# How to improve Limit clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, limit

I have the `posts` table with 10k rows and I want to create pagination by that. So I have the next query for that purpose:

```
SELECT post_id
    FROM posts
    LIMIT 0, 10;
```

When I `Explain` that query I get the next result:

[image]

So I don't understand why MySql need to iterate thru 9976 rows for finding the 10 first rows? I will be very thankful if somebody help me to optimize this query.

Also I know about that topic [MySQL ORDER BY / LIMIT performance: late row lookups](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/), but the problem still exist even if I modify the query to the next one:

```
SELECT  t.post_id
FROM    (
        SELECT  post_id
        FROM    posts
        ORDER BY
                post_id
        LIMIT 0, 10
        ) q 
JOIN    posts t 
ON      q.post_id = t.post_id
```

[image]

**Update**

@pala_'s solution works great for above simple case but now while I am testing a more complex query with `inner join`. My purpose is to join comment table with post table and unfortunately when I Explain new query is still iterate through 9976 rows.

```
Select comm.comment_id 
from comments as comm 
    inner join (
        SELECT post_id 
        FROM posts 
        ORDER BY post_id 
        LIMIT 0, 10
    ) as paged_post on comm.post_id = paged_post.post_id;
```

Do you have some idea what is the reason of such MySQL behavior ?

Comment: Why you need a derived part and join why not just one query with `select ..limit`

Comment: thats his first query, he's comparing them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT post_id
    FROM posts
    ORDER BY post_id DESC
    LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Pagination via `LIMIT` doesn't make much sense without ordering anyway, and it should fix your problem.

```
mysql> explain select * from foo;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo   | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   20 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from foo limit 0, 10;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo   | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   20 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from foo order by id desc limit 0, 10;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo   | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   10 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Regarding your last comments about the comment join. Do you have an index on `comment(post_id)`? with my test data I'm getting the following results:

```
mysql> alter table comments add index pi (post_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain select c.id from  comments c inner join (select id from posts o order by id  limit 0, 10) p on c.post_id = p.id;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |   10 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | c          | ref   | pi            | pi      | 5       | p.id |    4 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DERIVED     | o          | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   10 | Using index              |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

and for table size reference:

```
mysql> select count(*) from posts;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    15021 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from comments;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It works well. But I have one more question. Now I am testing more complex query with inner join. My purpose is to join comment table with post table and unfortunately when I Explain new query is still iterate thru 9976 rows. <<<
Select 
  comm.comment_id from comments as comm
inner join 
(SELECT post_id
    FROM posts
    ORDER BY post_id
    LIMIT 0, 10) as paged_post 
on comm.post_id = paged_post.post_id; >>>
Do you have some idea what is the reason of such MySQL behavior ?

Comment: try doing it without the subquery, and just add the limit to the end of the query , ie `explain select * from posts p inner join comments c on p.post_id = c.post_id order by p.post_id desc limit 0, 10`

Comment: I use subquery for pagination by posts. If I remove subquery and use just join like you mentioned above the pagination will break and I will get just first rows from joined table. Is there any other way to achieve the result with pagination by post?

Comment: oh. you want 10 posts and all comments thereof?

Comment: i don't actually get the same result as you. do you have an index on `comments`(post_id) ?

Comment: Yes I have index on comments(post_id). Just because  comments(post_id) is a foreign key so index  was created automatically in Innodb. And I have no idea what is the reason of different results =(.

Comment: can you include the output of 'explain' over that last query?

Comment: I moved this new question to the new [branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654576/how-to-improve-limit-clause-in-mysql-subquery?noredirect=1#comment47458905_29654576)